# Measuring the effect of increasing salinty on the concentration of Dissolved oxygen

Tags: water, aqueous-solution

I want to investigate the effect of increasing salinity on the concentration of dissolved oxygen, in a water sample being distilled water.
Would that work?

My concern is, that since its not a true fresh water sample, I am worried that changing the salinity of distilled water, to create different saline solutions, would impact the oxygen content significantly?

I want to model the direct relationship, so I can apply it to a real life example. For instance the effect of road salting on oxygen concentration in fresh water habitats.

Comment: Yes, salinity impacts dissolved oxygen content, as a little Googling will readily reveal (and deeper reading will show why). Your biggest problem would be - do you have the equipment needed to measure it properly?